# The best method to check if two numbers are equals

Tags: javascript, performance, if-statement

I wish know the best method to check if two number are equals.

I generate a simple example checking 10 million times if two numbers are equals.

This is in javascript and I comment the result in ms. I use chrome

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function goOn(arr) 
{
    var resul = 0;
    var a = 50;
    var b = 50;
    var fechai = new Date();
    for(i=0;i<10000000;i++)
    {
        //if(a ^ b === false)        // 1359
        //if((a & b) === a)         // 160
        //if(a === b)               // 148
        //if(!(a - b))              // 172
        if((a & ~b) === 0)           // 175
        {
            resul++;
        }
    }
    var fechaf = new Date();
    alert(fechaf - fechai);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" value="View message" onclick="goOn()">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why not just if(a===b){ ... ?

Comment: +1 for `(a === b)` => http://jsfiddle.net/aJWFe/1/

Comment: or, if you wan't to be "all that", Object.is() does the same as ===, but also claims that NaN===NaN...

Comment: @dandavis Why would he want `Object.is` to check if two numbers are equal -_-?

Comment: why `(a ^ b == false)`?  This has to convert a number to a boolean. `!(a ^ b)` is faster. (But still not as fast as simply using `==` or `===`, and fails in some cases)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum:  in case both of them are NaN, that's the only reason to ever use it...

Comment: `(a & ~b) === 0` will definitely not work. `0 & ~(-1) === 0`

Answer (score 3):

The best method to use to check for equality is the equality operators (`==` or `===`)  Using any other of those methods will just result in code that will massively confuse everybody without having any discernible performance impact.  (And if it did, this being JavaScript, any impact one way or the other would be entirely platform/browser dependent.)

In other words, don't do what you are trying to do.

Comment: true, but don't forget to also compare to NaN if you want to be 100% correct.

Comment: The best approach I can think of that includes NaN support is:

var equal = ( a === b || (a !== a) && (b !== b));